# how to display one image at a time using imageView

Tags: java, android, xml

My problem is that I want to display one image at a time on screen and every day my image will change. I am using imageView but it's showing all the images of notification.xml. I have searched a lot and I think I am missing some simple things. Plz help.

Notification.java is:

```
    package com.example.customcalendarandroid;
    import java.io.File;



    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

    public class NotificationView extends Activity{
       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
       {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.notification);
          //setContentView(R.layout.newxml);

         int i=10;
         if(i==10){
             ImageView   imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ekadashi_name2);
             imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.prabhu2);
         }else
         {
             ImageView   imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ekadashi_name3);
             imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.prabhu3); 
         }
         }
and 

notification.xml is

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"    >

    <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/ekadashi_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20sp"

        android:src="@drawable/krishna" />

  <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/ekadashi_name1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20sp"

        android:src="@drawable/prabhupada" />
     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/ekadashi_name2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20sp"

        android:src="@drawable/prabhu2" />
     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/ekadashi_name3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20sp"

        android:src="@drawable/prabhu3" />
     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/ekadashi_name4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20sp"

        android:src="@drawable/prabhu4" />
     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/ekadashi_name5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20sp"

        android:src="@drawable/prabhu5" />
     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/ekadashi_name6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20sp"

        android:src="@drawable/prabhu6" />




    <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/ekadashi_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20sp"

        android:src="@drawable/prabhupada1" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please put you xml file here

Answer (score 1):

You can use Array of images 
 like

```
    private int[] imagesArray = {
    R.drawable.img_00,
    R.drawable.img_01,
    R.drawable.img_02,
    };
```

Then u can do

```
    Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(imagesArray[i]);
    yourImageView.setImageDrawable(d);
```

just change the int i value every time when u want to load image

And in xml keep only one Image View that will work..u kept different image view for differentimage

hope that will help to u

Comment: This is the approach I'd go for

Answer (score 0):

This is always true:

```
int i=10;
if(i==10){
}
```

This program will always show ekadashi_name2. You have to change i to be a random number.

```
Random rn = new Random();
i = 1 + Random.nextInt(9);
```

With this, every time the application opens, a new image will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

take out  `android:src="@drawable/prabhupada"` parameter from all ImageView in xml .. then other image will not be set. By default you are providing imagesource to them.

or you can assign all other imageView to null

```
imageView.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);  // to set the image background null
```

Answer (score 0):

for each day, take any random image by findViewByID and set it's visibility to visble and show it and access all other images using findViewById and set their visibility either invisible or gone, as per your requirement!
   Also, instead of adding all images in xml, add only one image in your xml and do net set any source to it. Set source from java code, not from xml.